# pandas averaging data between timestamps

Tags: python, pandas

If I have some data (24 hours time series) read into Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


#read CSV file
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bbartling/Building-Demand-Electrical-Load-Profiles/master/july15.csv', 
                 index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
```

How can I average the `df` column `kW` between these time stamps into a new separate pandas df?

```
bkps_timestamps_kW = [
'2013-06-19 00:15:00',
'2013-06-19 05:15:00',
'2013-06-19 16:30:00',
'2014-06-18 00:00:00']
```

The new pandas df could have column names something like `avg_kw1, avg_kw2, avg_kw3` that would represent the averaging of the data between the time stamps in `bkps_timestamps_kW`

thanks for any help/tips

Comment: averaging you KW based on what? for each hour? can you add what is your desired output look like!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) for bining by your list converterted to datetimes and aggregate `mean`:

```
d = [
'2013-06-19 00:00:00',
'2013-06-19 00:15:00',
'2013-06-19 01:15:00',
'2013-06-19 05:15:00',
'2013-06-19 07:15:00',
'2013-06-19 16:30:00',
'2013-06-20 16:30:00',
'2014-06-18 00:00:00',
'2015-06-18 00:00:00']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':range(len(d))}, index=pd.to_datetime(d))
print (df)
                     Date
2013-06-19 00:00:00     0
2013-06-19 00:15:00     1
2013-06-19 01:15:00     2
2013-06-19 05:15:00     3
2013-06-19 07:15:00     4
2013-06-19 16:30:00     5
2013-06-20 16:30:00     6
2014-06-18 00:00:00     7
2015-06-18 00:00:00     8
```

---

```
bkps_timestamps_kW = [
'2013-06-19 00:15:00',
'2013-06-19 05:15:00',
'2013-06-19 16:30:00',
'2014-06-18 00:00:00']


b = pd.to_datetime(bkps_timestamps_kW)
labels = [f'{i}-{j}' for i, j in zip(bkps_timestamps_kW[:-1], bkps_timestamps_kW[1:])] 

df = df.groupby(pd.cut(df.index, bins=b, labels=labels)).mean()
print (df)
                                         Date
2013-06-19 00:15:00-2013-06-19 05:15:00   2.5
2013-06-19 05:15:00-2013-06-19 16:30:00   4.5
2013-06-19 16:30:00-2014-06-18 00:00:00   6.5
```

If need closed left intervals in `cut`:

```
df = df.groupby(pd.cut(df.index, bins=b, labels=labels, right=False)).mean()
print (df)
                                         Date
2013-06-19 00:15:00-2013-06-19 05:15:00   1.5
2013-06-19 05:15:00-2013-06-19 16:30:00   3.5
2013-06-19 16:30:00-2014-06-18 00:00:00   5.5
```

Comment: hello, can the code be modified to average between `'2013-06-19 00:15:00' - '2013-06-19 05:15:00'` and then `'2013-06-19 05:15:00' - '2013-06-19 16:30:00'` and then `'2013-06-19 16:30:00' - '2014-06-18 00:00:00'` 3 averages in total..?

Comment: @HenryHub - What should be expected output from `d = [
'2013-06-19 00:00:00',
'2013-06-19 00:15:00',
'2013-06-19 01:15:00',
'2013-06-19 05:15:00',
'2013-06-19 07:15:00',
'2013-06-19 16:30:00',
'2013-06-20 16:30:00',
'2014-06-18 00:00:00',
'2015-06-18 00:00:00']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':range(len(d))}, index=pd.to_datetime(d))` ?

Comment: Im just trying to average data between time stamps. Im looking at this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html

Comment: @HenryHub - My intention was if need `solution1` or `solution2`, so added boths. Difference is if counts also datetimes rows from start or from ends of intervals.